# Is it customary to tip medical doctors in Taiwan with expensive bottles of liquor?

Tags: health, taiwan, tipping

I am travelling to Taiwan to visit a relative-in-law who will be undergoing a pretty big surgery procedure. I'm not familiar at all with Taiwanese customs at all, but the relative in question asked that I bring a relatively expensive bottle of liquor ($100+) to "tip" the doctor with after the procedure has been completed.

This sounds all very strange and weird to me. I tried looking this up online, and it seems that [tipping culture is very unexpected in Taiwan asides from bellhops and service personnel](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g293910-s606/Taiwan:Tipping.And.Etiquette.html). When I asked another relative similar questions, they made a passing remark about how they tipped a doctor for their surgery a relatively expensive bottle of wine. I get the uncanny feeling that this relative is perhaps trying to fleece me for a pricey bottle of liquor but as I stated before, I have no idea if this is customary at all.  It just all sounds so weird especially considering the amount of money being paid to the hospital to have the procedure done in the first place.

Comment: Why are you doing the tipping when it's the relative having the surgery?

Comment: @Midavalo The reasoning they used was that in a previous surgery done a few years back, my sibling was the one who tipped that doctor with an expensive bottle of wine and some other expensive gifts.  Almost like playing a game of hot potato and I just happened to get the hot potato.

Comment: @yuritsuki Not familiar with Taiwan, but while Japan is also not a tipping culture, I've seen grateful patients give significant gifts (liquor, expensive skincare, etc) to doctors. However, this was always directly from patient to doctor, so here the fact that your relative is asking *you* to bring this is quite weird.  Is there a trusted third party you can check with?

Comment: I suspect the reason OP is being asked is so they can buy it at duty free

Comment: @MJeffryes They're being asked to gift it though, not just buy it...

Comment: Here in the US I'm already paying an arm and a leg to get surgeries done, so tipping the doctors afterwards with a gift feels dumb and financially unsound. I can't imagine why I'd do the same in any other country, unless the doctors were getting paid so little that gifting them an expensive bottle of liquor would be akin to tipping a waiter so that they can make ends meet.

Comment: Wouldn't this not be an issue if you just ask them to pay for it? You can set some limit like $30 you're willing to gift towards it.

Comment: If you are willing to give your relative a 100$ gift, then buy the bottle, otherwise do not buy it or ask your relative to pay for it. Whether the relative gives the bottle to a doctor or drinks it themselves is irrelevant: from your perspective, this is a gift from you to your relative.

Comment: It's a thank you gift. I don't know about Taiwan, but it's a common thing in Japan to give gifts (usually food) or even cash to doctors after a surgery.

Comment: @yuritsuki then get your surgeries done in Taiwan lol. The US is the most obnoxiously expensive place on earth for medical care because of the *positively bonkers* private multi-payer insurance system. There is no way to make that efficient and so procedures cost multiples more in the US than elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I am not familiar with Taiwan, I have heard of similar practices in European countries as well. You may call it a 'tip', but I would rather call it a bribe. Even if you, or some sort of insurance, pay for your treatment to the hospital, it may actually be required for proper service to give an additional compensation directly to the doctor.

A quick search on Google reveals that a similar practice is well known in Taiwan as well. According to [Gifts, bribes and solicitions: Print media and the social construction of informal payments to doctors in Taiwan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0277953606004679):

> The Taiwanese practice of patients giving informal payments to
> physicians to secure services is deeply rooted in social and cultural
> factors. ...

Comment: It's not a bribe (at least in layman terms) if you customarily do it after the treatment.

Comment: @alamar There is also a small but underlying worry that if I do not "tip" the doctor after the surgery is performed, the aftercare treatment may not be done properly or to the best of their abilities.  Which renders the gift as still some sort of "bribe"

Comment: @yuritsuki This is customarily done when you are discharged from the aftercare. You may also be inclined to thank the nurses in the same (but significantly reduced) fashion. Not sure about the Taiwan specifics, though :)

Comment: @alamar Did you read the article I linked to? Also the researchers behind that article use the term 'bribe'. By examining media coverage, they found that the payments were 'portrayed as a necessary part of gaining initial access to care' and that patients were 'worrying that doctors paid by a third party will not feel obliged to give quality care'. If you pay in the belief that it is required to get proper care or be treated at all, I don't see why the term 'bribe' is used incorrectly here.

Comment: @alamar It's not a bribe only if people go to the hospital once in their lifetime or their doctor's lifetime, whichever comes first. If you come more often than that, valuable gifts get you a better service than what the doctor provides to the poorer patients. Which is indeed a bribe.

Comment: It should be pointed out that if the doctor is employed or paid by a public agency, this is almost certainly an illegal bribe under laws about bribing foreign officials, such as Canada's Corruption of Foreign Public Officials Act (or the U.S. or U.K. equivalents) if the OP doesn't live in Taiwan, even if this were legal in Taiwan.  Penalties are usually severe.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: this is a modern form of bribe. Most developed countries have laws against bribes, so the classic form of bribe (giving money in exchange of a favor) has been replaced by gifts (it is more difficult to prove that a gift is to pay for a favor and not a genuine gesture). For example, I am teaching and researching in South Korea and I regularly receive emails from my administration to remind me and my colleagues that gifts from students are forbidden. It was very common in the past for teachers to receive money or expensive gifts in exchange for letters of recommendation.

Comment: See https://mcdaniel.hu/halapenz-plague-hungarian-healthcare-finally-cure/ for the Hungarian version.